# The main Nestjs module does not see the process.env.NODE_ENV variable

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have dynamic envFilePath in my main module, but `process.env.NODE_ENV` always == undefined.

`app.module.ts file`

```js
ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `src/config/env/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [configuration],
}),
```

But if I add printing this env inside bootstrap main method it works

`main.ts file`

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  console.log('ENV', process.env.NODE_ENV);

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  ...
}
```

console.log prints `dev`

**So the question is why inside my main app module this env is undefined?**

Comment: How do you populate `process.env`? By default, Node doesn't read any env files (though it can with node 20 and the `--env-file` flag), so `process.env` is unpopulated. There's packages like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and [`@nestjs/config`](https://github.com/nestjs/config) that uses dotenv under the hood, but you have to call `dotenv` yourself if you're using it and you have to call it before you import any files with decorators due to how that code gets handled. Otherwise you can do `NODE_ENV=whatever npm run start:dev`

Answer (score 0):

try to access it from ConfigFile

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';


const configService: ConfigService = app.get(ConfigService);
config.get('NODE_ENV')
```

Comment: Can I inject the configService from ConfigModule.forRoot({...  ??